# Calling variables in Python (local vs global)

Tags: python

The below works and gives 8:

```
def mypow(a,b):
    c=a**b
    print (c)

mypow(2,3)
```

But the below doesn't:

```
def mypow(a,b):
    c=a**b

mypow(2,3)
```

I understand that in the former we print but since the latter doesn't give an error message (nor does it give a result), what is actually happening in the latter?

Comment: You assign a value to a local variable and then do nothing with it.

Comment: and then the method does not return anything so returns None implicitly and ... nothing more is done.

Comment: If instead of assigning to c you instead do ```return a ** b```
you can then print the result by doing ```print(mypow(2,3))```

Comment: Such questions are best analyzed yourself - or you could post them to http://pythontutor.com and step through the code yourself.

Comment: you are nor returning nor printing. your function is doing calculations for no reason

Comment: this does not have to do with local vs global variables whatsoever

Comment: its becouse your function are processing the value but not returning nothing

Answer (score 1):

in

```python
def mypow(a,b):
    c=a**b

mypow(2,3)
```

after function executed; all data inside the function destroy. if you want to see anything on your screen after function is executed; either use `print` or `return`.

In the end of any function you have multiple choices.

1- `return`. return the output. when you return the output you receive it after function executed without error eg: `d = func(any_value)`, if you specified the return value in `func` you will receive it and store it in `d`. if you don't specify the return statement in the function the function will return `None`.

2- `print`. print anything. this is what you did in your first function. in this case you get printed stuff in your screen, and you function return `None`, so you can't hold the output (a printed value) in any variable or use it anywhere else.

3- `global`. assign to global. when you need this option you create a variable outside of your function say `my_variale=5`, and in the first line of your function you write `gloabl my_variable`. say the function contain 5 lines,  in line #3 you did `my_variable=7`. after function is executed and destroyed all values within the function; when you check `my_variable` you will see it contains value of `5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace print with return for your function and get the same result

```
def mypow(a,b):
    c=a**b
    return c

mypow(2,3)
```

Variables nested in functions are treated as local variables unless you add global before the variable name.